# mysql value to timer and keep increasing and updating till click stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, pdo, stopwatch

i am a situation here, i have a mysql table called attendance and there is a column named "break" in mysql TIME format 00:00:00 now i need a way to update the time according to user id upon when user clicks start and stop it when clicks stop.

found this bit of code here now can someone guide me through to achieve my goal?

my sql query is

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT MAX(attn_id) AS id FROM attendance WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['member_id']."'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();  
   timervalue = $row['break'];      
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE attendance SET break = '".timervalue."' WHERE attn_id= '".$row['id']."'");
$stmt->execute();
```

by default the value in break is stored as 00:00:00

how can i impliment the below code to make it update my database? also get rid of the milliseconds i only need h:m:s

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {

  // Some global variables
  var startTime = 0,
      elapsed   = 0,
      timerId   = 0,
      $timer    = $("#timer");
  
  function formatTime(time) {
    var hrs = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60 / 1000),
        min = Math.floor((time - hrs*60*60*1000) / 60 / 1000),
        sec = Math.floor((time - hrs*60*60*1000 - min*60*1000) / 1000);
    
    hrs = hrs < 10 ? "0" + hrs : hrs;
    min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
    sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
    
    return hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  }
  
  function elapsedTimeFrom(time) {
    return formatTime(time - startTime + elapsed);
  }
  
  function showElapsed() {
    $timer.text(elapsedTimeFrom(Date.now()));
  }
  
  function startTimer() {
    // React only if timer is stopped
    startTime = startTime || Date.now();
    timerId = timerId || setInterval(showElapsed, 1000);
  }
  
  function pauseTimer() {
    // React only if timer is running
    if (timerId) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      elapsed += Date.now() - startTime;
      startTime = 0;
      timerId = 0;
    }
  }
  
  function resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    $timer.text("01:00:00");
    startTime = 0;
    elapsed = 0;
    timerId = 0;
  }

  function editTimer() {
    pauseTimer();
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", true);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid red");
  }

  function setElapsed() {
    var time = $timer.text(),
        arr  = time.split(":");
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", false);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid black");
    elapsed = parseInt(arr[0]*60*60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[1]*60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[2], 10);
    elapsed *= 1000;
  }
  
  function sendTime() {
    pauseTimer();
    // Set hidden input value before send
    $("[name='time']").val(formatTime(elapsed));
  }

  $("[name='start']").click(startTimer);
  $timer.dblclick(editTimer);
  $timer.blur(setElapsed);
  $("form").submit(sendTime);
  
});
 </script>
 <h1><div id="timer">00:00:00</span></div>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="button" name="start" value="Start">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="time" value="00:00:00">
</form>
```

Really appreciate whole hearty for helping me ot and giving your valuable time and input.

Thanks

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry that i will manage but can you help me with the question?

Comment: I would rather start with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/34tvmoka/

Comment: And just add a submit button to that

Comment: @Strawberry i just needed start and then submit and also how to start from database stored time? please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'proof-of-concept'...

```
<?php

/*
-- TABLE CREATION STATEMENTS
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table (t TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('00:01:50');
*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

//If something was posted, update the table. Otherwise, skip this step...
if(sizeof($_POST) != 0){ 
$x=$_POST['tts'];
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET t = SEC_TO_TIME(?) LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$x]);
}

//Grab the stored value from the database...
$query = "
select t
     , time_to_sec(t) tts
     , LPAD(HOUR(t),2,0) h
     , LPAD(MINUTE(t),2,0) i
     , LPAD(SECOND(t),2,0) s
  from my_table
 limit 1
   ";

//Format the data for ease of use...
if ($data = $pdo->query($query)->fetch()) {
$t = $data['t'];
$tts = $data['tts'];
$h = $data['h'];
$i = $data['i'];
$s = $data['s'];

} else {
$t = 0;
$tts = 0;
$h = '00';
$i = '00';
$s = '00';
}

?>

//Make a simple form, with one, hidden input...
<form id="myForm" method="post">
<input name="tts" type= "hidden" id="tts" value="tts">
<span id="hour"><?php echo $h; ?></span>:
<span id="min"><?php echo $i; ?></span>:
<span id="sec"><?php echo $s; ?></span>

<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start/Resume">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">

<button id="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The timer/stopwatch thingy-->
<script>
var Clock = {
  totalSeconds: <?php echo $tts ?>,
  start: function () {
    if (!this.interval) {
        var self = this;
        function pad(val) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
          self.totalSeconds += 1;

          $("#hour").text(pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600 % 60)));
          $("#min").text(pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60)));
          $("#sec").text(pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60)));

          <!-- Also provide data in seconds, for ease of use -->             
          <!-- Note, this is 'val', not 'text'               -->
          $("#tts").val(pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds)));

        }, 1000);
    }
  },

  pause: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
  },

  resume: function () {
    this.start();
  }
};


$('#startButton').click(function () { Clock.start(); });
$('#pauseButton').click(function () { Clock.pause(); });
</script>
```